# Django Test Client squishes nested JSON

Tags: django, django-testing

I'm having a problem very similar to [Django's Querydict bizarre behavior: bunches POST dictionary into a single key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315960/djangos-querydict-bizarre-behavior-bunches-post-dictionary-into-a-single-key) and [Unit testing Django JSON View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794457/unit-testing-django-json-view). However, none of the questions/responses in these threads really point at the specify problem I'm having. I'm trying to use Django's test client to send a request with a nested JSON object (what I have works well with JSON objects with non-JSON values).

**Attempt #1:** Here's my initial code:

```
    response = c.post('/verifyNewMobileUser/', 
        {'phoneNumber': user.get_profile().phone_number,
         'pinNumber': user.get_profile().pin,
         'deviceInfo': {'deviceID': '68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067', 'deviceType': 'I'}})
```

As you can see, I have a nested JSON object within my request data. However, this is what request.POST looks like:

```
<QueryDict: {u'phoneNumber': [u'+15551234567'], u'pinNumber': [u'4171'], u'deviceInfo': [u'deviceType', u'deviceID']}>
```

**Attempt #2:** Then I tried, adding on the content-type parameter as follows:

```
response = c.post('/verifyNewMobileUser/', 
    {'phoneNumber': user.get_profile().phone_number,
     'pinNumber': user.get_profile().pin,
     'deviceInfo': {'deviceID': '68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067', 'deviceType': 'I'}},
    'application/json')
```

And what I get now for request.POST is

```
<QueryDict: {u"{'deviceInfo': {'deviceType': 'I', 'deviceID': '68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067'}, 'pinNumber': 5541, 'phoneNumber': u' 15551234567'}": [u'']}>
```

All I want to do is be able to specify a nested dict for my request data. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following works for me (using named args):

```
geojson = {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [1, 2]
    }

    response = self.client.post('/validate', data=json.dumps(geojson),
                                content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: JSON.dumps is the best way to do it. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: But this doesn't work with multipart form data, with nested dict.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem indicates Django is interpreting your request as `multipart/form-data` rather than `application/json`.  Try

`c.post("URL", "{JSON_CONTENT}", content_type="application/json")`.

Another thing to watch is that Python represents dictionary keys/values using single quotes when rendered as strings, which the simplejson parser doesn't like.  Keep your hard-coded JSON objects as single-quoted strings, using double quotes inside to get around this...

Answer (score 0):

My solution is the following:

In the test method:

```
data_dict = {'phoneNumber': user.get_profile().phone_number,
             'pinNumber': user.get_profile().pin,
             'deviceInfo':
                 {'deviceID': '68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067',
                  'deviceType': 'I'}})

self.client.post('/url/', data={'data': json.dumps(data_dict)})
```

In the view:

```
json.loads(request.POST['data'])
```

This sends post['data'] as a string. The in the view one must load the json from that string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `json.dumps` doesn't address the issue in many cases. Rather, I use it more selectively as such:

```
data = {
    "values": {
        "one": 1,
        "two": 2
    }
}
```

When doing the following: `self.client.post("/endpoint/", json.dumps(data))` one can stumble into JSON decoding errors, particularly with single/double quote issues.

The approach that I find works, which I still don't love, is to alter the data object as follows:

```
data = {
    "values": json.dumps({
        "one": 1,
        "two": 2
    })
}
```

Here th JSON encoding happens the the inner level of the data such that parsing the response like `request.POST.get("values")` results in the expected dictionary object.